# Regular Expression in C# (Regex)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've got the following input text:

> 10,"ABASTECEDORA NAVAL Y INDUSTRIAL, S.A.",-0- ,"CUBA"

I need a `String[] result` with

```
result[0] == "10"
result[1] == "ABASTECEDORA NAVAL Y INDUSTRIAL, S.A."
result[2] == "-0-"
result[3] == "CUBA"
```

Please help to give me a regex pattern to split the input for above result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are reading a CSV file with optional quotations and you want to parse a single line. Take a look at this excellent .NET CSV reader API:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

Comment: jmacinnes : Yes , i should use CSV Reader!!!! thank you

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this may be a CSV file that you are reading in, if so you should use the .NET CSV api.

However if you really want to use regex, you can use the `Regex.split()` function to split your input into a `String[]`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx

Comment: Hunter McMillen : Yes , i should use CSV Reader!!!! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work with your specific example:

```
(\d+),"([^"]+)",([^,]+),"([^"]+)"
```

However, it looks like you're really parsing CSV, so I'd use an appropriate CSV library for this.  The pattern I provided won't account for embedded and escaped quotations / commas within the String, etc.

Comment: ziesemer : Yes , i should use CSV Reader!!!! thank you